# How to make code synchronous in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I know its not recommended to create add async to useEffect but how can I make sure my function is completely done before continuing

Here is my code

```
useEffect(
   () => {
         const RetrieverDataProcess = async () => {
             const GetMainListResults = await GetMainList(FORMSTATUS.ID);
             setMAINOBJECT(GetMainListResults); //useState
             console.log(2)
         }

         console.log(1);
         RetrieverDataProcess();
         console.log(99);

    }, [])
```

If I run in my console its showing

1

99

2

I was hopeing its

1

2

99

Comment: Possible duplicate of [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 4):

Are you doing this because you want the `MAINOBJECT` state property to be set by the time you're ready to execute `console.log(99)`?

If so, one thing you could do is use an additional `useEffect` hook that only executes when the state property `MAINOBJECT` updates:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (MAINOBJECT) {
    console.log(99);
  }
}, [MAINOBJECT]);
```

Comment: What I want to achieve was after RetrieverDataProcess function is completed, I will turn off my loading screen. For now I just added console log to make it simple.

Comment: Since you're setting the state property MAINOBJECT at the end of RetrieverDataProcess, the solution I provided should work. Try to execute your loading screen logic within the additional hook I suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this (not at pc right now)

```
useEffect(
   () => {
         const RetrieverDataProcess = async () => {
             const GetMainListResults = await GetMainList(FORMSTATUS.ID);
             setMAINOBJECT(GetMainListResults); //useState
             return console.log(2)
         }

         console.log(1);
         RetrieverDataProcess().then(()=>{
             console.log(99);
         });


    }, [])
```

Comment: I am ok using then but doesnt it breaking the async/await idea.

Comment: if i would be you i would put console.log(99)   inside the function(after console2), :P but you wanted it like this

Comment: The async/await concept only applies within the async function. Outside of it, you are back to Promises. @giorgim had the right explaination, but he has deleted his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may use an **Immediately Invoked Function Expression** or **IFFY**. This will also allow you to use async/await instead of going back to then-chaining.

Essentially you are wrapping the effect body in an async function, which you immediately invoke.

```js
useEffect(() => {
     (async function anyName() {
         const RetrieverDataProcess = async () => {
             const GetMainListResults = await GetMainList(FORMSTATUS.ID);
             setMAINOBJECT(GetMainListResults); //useState
             console.log(2);
         }

         console.log(1);
         // now you can await the async function to make sure it completes
         await RetrieverDataProcess();
         console.log(99);
     // note the invocation:
     })();
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put your logic outside the EFFECT.

You can define an async function in component and then call it in EFFECT. If you care the performance, wrap it with `useCallback`.  Don't forget setting it as a dependency.

The better practice is to extract the static logic into small functions outside the component.

Comment: Example would be great. if you could.